# StringEscapeUtils escapeJava is escaping pound signs

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to escape a string to ensure that special characters are escaped.

Using

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("")  escapes to \\uD83D\\uDE00

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("% ! @ $ ^ & * ") doesn't escape any of the characters

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("£") escapes to \\u00A3
```

I can understand that emojis contain backslashes and so are escaped, but why is the pound sign being escaped, and how do I stop it from being escaped?

Comment: Never used Commons utils but I'd recommend you to read JavaDocs of `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`.

Comment: @Sufian The [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-) doesn't mention pound symbols. I don't understand why this was downvoted - I think this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: The documentation says: Escapes the characters in a String using `Java String rules`. So, Sufian is right

Comment: I suppose it is escaping everything that is not included in 7-bit ASCII. The pound sign is not included in 7-bit ASCII, it is included in the extended ASCII (8-bit). And, also escaping "quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)", ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` is vague on exactly what "Java String rules" are.

I guess it is referring to the bit in [JLS Chapter 3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html), where it says:

> Programs are written in Unicode (§3.1), but lexical translations are provided (§3.2) so that Unicode escapes (§3.3) can be used to include any Unicode character using only ASCII characters.

and

> ASCII (ANSI X3.4) is the American Standard Code for Information Interchange. The first 128 characters of the Unicode UTF-16 encoding are the ASCII characters.

So it might mean *escaping the string so that it can be written using only ASCII characters*.

`%`, `!`, `@`, `$`, `^`, `&` and `*` are all ASCII characters. They have values less than 128 (i.e. they are in the 7-bit block).

`£` isn't an ASCII character: in ISO8859-1, it is encoded as 163 (0xA3), which is outside the 7-bit ASCII block.

If you open a file with the `£` in a string literal, it might be rendered as something else, if that editor doesn't set the character encoding correctly. For example, it could be `Ł`, if it's interpreted in ISO8859-2.

In order to be unambiguous, the pound sign is therefore escaped.

> how do I stop it from being escaped

You can't, using this method; you'd need to find an alternative. The only thing you can do would be to replace the `\u00A7`s in the string with `£` again.

Comment: Java source files are not guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded. On most platforms and in IDEs such as eclipse they will be encoded in whatever the platform default is, which on for example os x would not be UTF-8. A good practice is to force UTF-8 as the default in your IDEs and build files. So, given that, escape is doing the right thing. If you are not doing this, you will at some point get some funny issues if somebody uses some characters outside the ascii range in e.g. variable names or string literals.